# R package "feather" give me error "Error in check_dots_empty(action = signal) : unused argument (action = signal)"

Tags: r, feather

I start getting a very strange error from the "feather" package in R:

Let say I write and read file

```
write_feather(mtcars, 'm')
read_feather('m')
```

The last one gives me

```
Error in check_dots_empty(action = signal) : 
  unused argument (action = signal)
```

I reinstalled the package, restarted sessions, and still have no idea how to fix it. R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)

Please, help me

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue on R version 4.0.2 and feather 0.3.5.

Comment: It's very strange because it starts happens on my AWS instance today.
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
feather => ‘0.3.5’
Maybe some caches for R or R Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found at the end:

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tibble", force = TRUE)
```

The problem lies in updated code for 'read_feather' function.
It now using 'as_tibble' function. By updating 'tibble' package this starts working fine.

Here is the code of 'read_feather' in new version:

tibble: 3.1.0 - feather: 0.3.5 - read_feather

```
function (path, columns = NULL) 
{
    data <- feather(path)
    on.exit(close(data), add = TRUE)
    if (is.null(columns)) 
        as_tibble(data)
    else as_tibble(data[columns])
}
```

Here is the code of 'read_feather' in previous version:

tibble: 3.0.1 - feather: 0.3.5 - read_feather

```
function (file, col_select = NULL, as_data_frame = TRUE, ...) 
{
    reader <- FeatherTableReader$create(file, ...)
    all_columns <- ipc___feather___TableReader__column_names(reader)
    col_select <- enquo(col_select)
    columns <- if (!quo_is_null(col_select)) {
        vars_select(all_columns, !!col_select)
    }
    out <- reader$Read(columns)
    if (isTRUE(as_data_frame)) {
        out <- as.data.frame(out)
    }
    out
}
```